# Tracing Guarded Blocks in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

I've been struggling for a couple days with this simple concurrency Oracle problem which models a Producer/Consumer. This is the first time I've used guarded blocks, wait, and notifyAll. I know what these methods do, however; I don't what steps occur first. I'm going to trace the problem as best as I can down below and you guys can tell me if I'm right.

1. The Producer/Consumer thread is started from the main thread. Each is given the same Drop instance.
2. If the Consumer Thread is faster then the Producer, its acquires the intrinsic lock on drop and tries to print out the message from `drop.take()` in a loop. However, the producer has not given the consumer the message because `empty` is true. This results in the thread being suspended and the lock is released. It is now waiting.
3. The Producer Thread calls `drop.put()` in a loop. It acquires the intrinsic lock on drop and continues the method because `empty` is true and it needs to prepare the message for Consumer. It sets `empty` to false and stores the message. `notifyAll()` is called which wakes up the Consumer Thread. The Producer is also waiting because `empty` is now false and the lock is released.
4. Since the `drop.take()` was notified and Producer had the intrinsic lock on drop, it wakes up the method. `Empty` is set to true and the message is returned and printed in the loop. It now notifies the Producer thread to wake up because it needs a new message.
5. Producer has been waiting. Since `empty` is true and the thread has been notified(and the lock was accessed), it can now wake up and produces another message.

Drop Class

```html
package Store;

public class Drop {
    // Message sent from producer
    // to consumer.
    private String message;
    // True if consumer should wait
    // for producer to send message,
    // false if producer should wait for
    // consumer to retrieve message.
    private boolean empty = true;

    public synchronized String take() {
        // Wait until message is
        // available.
        while (empty) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        // Toggle status.
        empty = true;
        // Notify producer that
        // status has changed.
        notifyAll();
        return message;
    }

    public synchronized void put(String message) {
        // Wait until message has
        // been retrieved.
        while (!empty) {
            try { 
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        // Toggle status.
        empty = false;
        // Store message.
        this.message = message;
        // Notify consumer that status
        // has changed.
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Consumer Class:

```html
package Store;

import java.util.Random;


public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private Drop drop;

    public Consumer(Drop drop) {
        this.drop = drop;
    }

    public void run() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (String message = drop.take();
             ! message.equals("DONE");
             message = drop.take()) {
            System.out.format("MESSAGE RECEIVED: %s%n", message);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(5000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Producer Class:

```html
package Store;


import java.util.Random;

public class Producer implements Runnable {
    private Drop drop;

    public Producer(Drop drop) {
        this.drop = drop;
    }

    public void run() {
        String importantInfo[] = {
            "Mares eat oats",
            "Does eat oats",
            "Little lambs eat ivy",
            "A kid will eat ivy too"
        };
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0;
             i < importantInfo.length;
             i++) {
            drop.put(importantInfo[i]);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(5000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        drop.put("DONE");
    }
}
```

Main Thread:

```html
public class ProducerConsumerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Drop drop = new Drop();
        (new Thread(new Producer(drop))).start();
        (new Thread(new Consumer(drop))).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a full answer, but I do have a couple of observations.

The while wrapping the wait will lead to exceptions if they ever loop. wait requires a lock, but wait releases the lock. Fortunately, you should not experience that behavior.

You may run into problems with your instance variables not updating across threads. You synchronize, then wait. That provides an opportunity for those variables to have different values. Marking them volatile would help with that.

You didn't say what your code actually does...

Comment: I was just tracing the steps for the first message which would repeat for the other messages. I liked what you said about how wait requires and releases the lock.